# An infinite sum of lengths.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let both the base and height of the following triangle have the length 6m. If the lines drawn inside the triangle bisect each right angle formed while proceeding. Then find the length of all these lines. The reason i could not do it is that i did not find any series representation of the lengths of the lines.

[image: triangle having lines drawn inside it starting from the right angle and reflected by the hypotenuse such that the reflected line is parallel to the x axis. This continues until the line reaches the other vertice.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First length element is

> $$
> \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2} a
> $$

Second length element is

> $$
> \frac{1}{2} a
> $$

Now you repeat this for a smaller triangle with

> $$
> \frac{1}{2} a
> $$

Then

> $$
> \Bigg( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots \Bigg)
> \Big( 1 + \sqrt{2} \Big) a
> $$

Result

> $$
> = \Big( 1 + \sqrt{2} \Big) a
> $$

---

> $$
> S = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots
> $$

So

> $$
> 2 S = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots
> $$

Difference gives

> $$
> S = 2S - S = 1
> $$

Comment: What is the sum of that 1/2+1/4+1/8+..... Can you prove it.

Comment: Added that to the answer...

Comment: Excellent. Very goo.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the diagonals is $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} 6 \ast 2^{-1/2} \ast 2^{-j}$. The sum of the horizontals is  $\sum_{j=1}^\infty 6\ast 2^{-j}$. The sum is thus $$3\sqrt{2} + 6(1+2^{-1/2})\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j}=6(\sqrt{2} + 1)$$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

length in meters of horizontals: $6\times\frac12$, $6\times\left(\frac12\right)^2$,... etc.

length in meters of other lines: $6\sqrt2\times\frac12$, $6\sqrt2\times\left(\frac12\right)^2$,... etc.